# Writing animation (only Javascript usage NO CSS ANIMATION!) directives in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, animation, angularjs-directive, jquery-animate

I am writing a module in angularjs which would mainly support IE 8 and 9.
Now the animation directives available in the lib uses mainly CSS transitions and it fails. So I am planning to write Javascript based animations by using angular js directives and develop basic animations like collapse, disappear etc.
What should be the  approach for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check great examples on [Year Of Moo](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/04/animation-in-angularjs.html) website. They were really helpful for me.